# Weird C++ library linkage issue with clion and cygwin

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, c++, c

I have the following error when trying to compile a c++ program while linking the library Libssh on Windows (packages libssh-common and libssh-devel both installed with cygwin). Clion doesn't give me an include error and cmake finds the library during the Cmake reload of Clion, but when compiling/linking it complains that the references are undefined.

Could someone point out my stupid mistake?
Thanks in advance!

```
Scanning dependencies of target main
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable main.exe
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `ssh_new'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x30): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `ssh_new'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my CmakeLisst.txt

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)
find_package(LIBSSH)
IF (LIBSSH_FOUND)
    message(${LIBSSH_VERSION})
    include_directories(${LIBSSH_INCLUDE_DIR})
    link_directories(${LIBSSH_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(main ${LIBSSH_LIBRARIE})
endif ()
```

output Cmake reload

```
C:\Users\seven\.CLion2018.3\system\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE= -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/cygwin64/bin/make.exe -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=C:/cygwin64/bin/gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:/cygwin64/bin/g++.exe -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" "/cygdrive/c/Users/seven/Documents/github/Server control"
0.7.5
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /cygdrive/c/Users/seven/Documents/github/Server control/cmake-build-default-cygwin

[Finished]
```

main.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#define LIBSSH_STATIC 1
#include <libssh\libssh.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    ssh_session my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
    return 0;
}
```

--update 1--
 CmakeOutput.log
[github gist](https://gist.github.com/tibovanheule/069ec45700572d34fb91f85ec0c0844c)

--SOLUTION----

Had to change my cmakelist to the following

```
find_package(LIBSSH)
IF (LIBSSH_FOUND)
    message(${LIBSSH_VERSION})
    include_directories(${LIBSSH_INCLUDE_DIR})
    link_directories(${LIBSSH_LIBRARY_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(main -L${LIBSSH_LIBRARY} -lssh)
endif ()
```

Comment: Are you completely positive the `LIBSSH_FOUND` part in `CMakeLists.txt` is executed? Try to inspect `CMakeOutput.log` and `CMakeError.log` for making sure and possible helpful hints

Comment: @valiano Well, it manages to print out the correct version number, so I thought the block executed. I tried to find CMakeError.log but it isn't present in my project files. I don't find any weird entries in `CmakeOutput.log` but I find nothing about libssh either. I will give a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/tibovanheule/069ec45700572d34fb91f85ec0c0844c)

Comment: Thanks for the gist Tibo_Vanheule. It's difficult for me to say whether libssh is indeed picked. You can check whether it's actually linked against with: run `make VERBOSE=1` from the command line, where your project `Makefile` is located (possibly change one source file to force the build). Then, look for the `ld` command line in the build output.

Comment: Okay, so after running `make VERBSOE=1`. I looked in the output and didn't found the ld command. [make verbose output](https://gist.github.com/tibovanheule/7544acf0bad2c684bf7917a087207534) .Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from `make VEBOSE=1` output, the libssh library is indeed not linked against.

Try fixing these lines in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
link_directories(${LIBSSH_LIBRARY_DIR})
target_link_libraries(main ${LIBSSH_LIBRARY})
```

- The parameter to `link_directories` should be `LIBSSH_LIBRARY_DIR`, rather than `LIBSSH_INCLUDE_DIR`.
- The parameter to `target_link_libraries` should be `LIBSSH_LIBRARY`, rather than `LIBSSH_LIBRARIE`.

Or, alternatively:

```
link_directories(${LIBSSH_LIBRARY_DIR})
target_link_libraries(main -L${LIBSSH_LIBRARY_DIR} -lssh")
```

Comment: Thank you, it fixes the link, but gave new error, sadly! `make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/cygssh.dll', needed by 'main.exe'.  Stop. ` [new verbose gist](https://gist.github.com/tibovanheule/99192b5d321417304ba20eb33c0ef0a5) and yes i installed all openssh related packages

Comment: Hmm... You get `cygssh.dll`, but I think you're really looking for `libssh.a`. What if you use `target_link_libraries(main -L${LIBSSH_LIBRARY_DIR} -lssh")`? Or, even hard code the path to `libssh.a`, if nothing else works.

Comment: It now compiles perfectly, Thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: @tibovanheule gladly!